# Creating Basic Jquery plugin ? error :object expected ,Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am trying to learn building own jquery plugin . with the simple example but i am getting error while executing it .planning to build plugin for

> Loan calculator

can some help me regarding  error "

> Object Expected

my javascript in the index.html goes like this  ...

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function() {
     var roi=getie();  //  ROI - rate of interest - value of i receved from function getie()
    $("#i").val(roi);  // input type 'text ' to display Interest (i) value
    });

});
```

and the plugin codgin for custom function

> getie()

goes like this in separate

> calculate.js  file

CODE :

```
(function($){
    //Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 
            //This is where you write your plugin's name
       getie: function() {
            //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
            return this.each(function() {
             var  i=20;
             return i;
             });
        }
    });


})(jQuery);
```

i am using  jquery-1.7.2.min.js and query-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js  as other js file in this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$.fn.extend` you extend jquery and don't create an object. So you must call it on a jquery object:

```
$(this).getie()
```

Comment: @Thomos if use $(this).get()   we are getting this as output " [object Object]  "

Comment: The problem I think is in `return this.each` which returns the passed jquery object. The `return i` doesn't return the getie function.
`getie: function() {
            //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
            var i = 20;
            this.each(function() {
                //Do something with i
            });
             return i;
        }`
http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/NhH7P/

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling

```
roi = $('someSelector').getie()
```

'Object expected' means you should have been passing your function an object, in this case the jQuery object or some jQuery-wrapped set.

Comment: matthewdavidson, my aim is to get the integer value in return from the function and it should be assigned var roi , how can i use selector here

Comment: Well you can also call $().getie() if you aren't operating on a wrapped set, that will just invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need getie to be a jQuery plugin? The way you are using it and 
or what it does a regular function would suffice

```
function getie(){
}
```

Comment: that's true already i done the entire coding of Loan Calculator using just regular function and its working well  and becouse my  loan calculation based on different scenarios making code complex and i want to achieve this as j query plugin